# bash automate the user input <enter> in the loop

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/sh
dom=$(date '+%d') # 01-31, day of month
year=$(date '+%Y') # four-digit year
month=$(date '+%m') # two-digit month


nworkdays=0
for d in $( seq 1  $dom)
 do
    today=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%x') # locale's date representation (e.g. 12/31/99)
    dow=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%u')   # day of week: 1-7 with 1=Monday, 7=Sunday
    if [ "$dow" -le 5 ]  && grep -vq "$today"
    then
        workday=Yes
        nworkdays=$((nworkdays+1))


    else
        workday=

    fi
done
[ "$workday" ] && [ "$nworkdays" -eq 6 ] && echo "$nworkdays $today $workday"
~
```

I wanted to execute the script but the script goes inside the loop and asks for user input.

Expected result 
on execution display workday

Best Regards,
Shalini

Comment: `grep -vq "$today"` is waiting for input to grep your value of `$today` from ...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @urbanespacemen kindly  remove the grep command

```
#!/bin/sh
dom=$(date '+%d') # 01-31, day of month
year=$(date '+%Y') # four-digit year
month=$(date '+%m') # two-digit month

nworkdays=0
for d in $( seq 1  $dom)
 do
    today=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%x') # locale's date representation (e.g. 12/31/99)
    dow=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%u')   # day of week: 1-7 with 1=Monday, 7=Sunday
    if [ "$dow" -le 5 ]
    then
        workday=Yes
        nworkdays=$((nworkdays+1))

    else
        workday=

    fi
done

[ "$workday" ] && [ "$nworkdays" -eq 6 ] && echo "$nworkdays $today $workday"
```

Now should work